# Meaning and how to get and work with a return value from a user input in a method in java

Tags: java, loops

I am trying to write a java program which have two classes. The second class will have the main method and for checking the balance of the account and. The first class will have three methods one for opening  an bank account, one for deposit and one for withdrawal. All input needs to be given by  user. I am new to java and stuck after at one point any help would be appreciated.

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

class Balance {
    static int account()
    {   Scanner minimumAmount = new Scanner(System.in);
        int openingAmount = minimumAmount.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please deposit an amount more than Rs. 1000.00 to open a Bank account:" + openingAmount);
        if (openingAmount > 1000)
        {
            System.out.println("Your Bank account has opened successfully");
            int ac = minimumAmount.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter your account number" + ac);
        }
    }
    static int withdrawal() {
        Scanner withdrawalAmount = new Scanner(System.in);
        int w = withdrawalAmount.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount is :" + w);
        int b = openingAmount - w;
        if (b < 100) {
            System.out.println("Unable to process your request");
        }
    }
    void deposit() {
        Scanner depositAmount = new Scanner(System.in);
        int d = depositAmount.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Deposited amount is :" + d);
        int b = openingAmount + d;
    }
}
public class AccountBalance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Balance s = new Balance();
        s.account();
        s.withdrawal();
        s.deposit();
    }
}
```

i) Is there a way  where an user input variable declared under one method can be used in another method to declare another variable?

ii) ow to return a value from a method so that the value received works in different method while declaring a variable?

Comment: i) You could either use global variables: `class Balance{ float amount = 0; ...` and use them everywhere in your class, or use parameters to call your functions. `void deposit(float amount) { System.out.println("Deposited " + amount + " dollar"); }`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way where an user input variable declared under one method
>   can be used in another method to declare another variable?

You can declare your attribute in your class and use constructor to initialize it for example :

```
class A{

   private String name;

   public A(String name){
      this.name = name
   }

   public int account(){
      //can use and change the name
   }
   public int withdrawal(){
      //can use and change the name
   }
   public int deposit(){
      //can use and change the name
   }
}
```

Main class

```
public class B{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A s = new A("Hello");
        //------------^^---pass your attribute in the constructor    
        s.account();
        s.withdrawal();
        s.deposit();
    }
}
```

> How to return a value from a method so that the value received works
>   in different method while declaring a variable?

You can use the result of each method in another method for example :

```
s.withdrawal(s.account());
//--------------^^-------account return a result that can be used by withdrawal
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really want to do, but I can explain some things.

- Methods account() & withdrawal() don't have to be static.
- You can use instance attribute like I do to store values.
- Balance & AccountBalance should be in different files.
- Take a look about private & public on attribut & methods (& getter/setter)
- Scanner is a little bit tricky so you should declare it once, and reuse it.
- If you want to use returned value from function, change void by int (in this case) and use "return var" (var is what you want to return). So when you can call the function like this -> int value = s.account();

Try this code, it works.

Cheers !

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Balance {

    private Scanner scanner;
    public int userAccount;
    public int userAccountNumber;

    public Balance() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }

    public void account() {
        System.out.print("Please deposit an amount more than Rs. 1000.00 to open a Bank account : ");
        int openingAmount = scanner.nextInt();

        if (openingAmount > 1000) {
            System.out.println("Your Bank account has opened successfully");
            userAccount = openingAmount;
            System.out.println("Enter your account number : ");
            userAccountNumber = scanner.nextInt();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not enought money");
            this.account(); //Ask again for opening an account
        }
    }

    public void withdrawal() {
        System.out.println("Withdrawal Amount is : ");
        int w = scanner.nextInt();
        int b = userAccount - w;
        if (b < 100) {
            System.out.println("Unable to process your request");
        } else {
            userAccount = b;
        }
    }

    public void deposit() {
        System.out.println("Deposited amount is : ");
        int d = scanner.nextInt();
        userAccount += d;
    }
}
public class AccountBalance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Balance s = new Balance();
        s.account();
        s.withdrawal();
        s.deposit();
        System.out.println("Final amount is : "+s.userAccount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for your time and effort..!! :)